# I want to calculate the Average Sales Amount of the Sellers that make 80% of the sales of the whole division. Division Changes.(No VBA please)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel with:
Column A: Division.
Column B: Seller Name
Column C: Sales Amount.

I want to first Identify what sellers contribute colectivley to 80% of the total sales within each division. This is complicated because I dont know how to make a formula restart when it changes division (I have over 100 divisions).

Then I want to calculate the average sales amount of thoes sellers.

[image]

In Column D, I applied this formula to know the total amount of sales of each division.
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, A2)

In Column E I divided de Sales of the Seller with column D, and so I got the % of wheigt of that particular seller in the division.

But cant manage to sum up the % of each Seller in the division and then restart the sum up dinamically when the division change ( I have over 100 divisions).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is already in a table or could be.

1. Custom sort the table by Division and then Sales
2. Populate column F using: `=SUM(INDEX(Table1[[#All],[% Wieght within the Division]],MATCH([@Division],Table1[[#All],[Division]],0)):[@[% Wieght within the Division]])`
3. Conditionally format column F using: `=AND(F1>0.8,F2>0.8)` with the font color set to white